# Filling a matrix with smaller blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, data-structures

Given a `n*m matrix.`

```
[[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]]
```

Then we need to fill in the matrix with smaller blocks such that the new blocks occupy empty space and don't overlap with existing blocks.

For example, after putting a block of 2*2, the matrix looks as below:

```
[[1,1,0,0]
[1,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]]
```

Return `-1` if no space available in the bigger matrix.

**My Code:**

```
matrix_m = 4
matrix_n = 3

block_m = 2
block_n = 2

matrix = [[0]*matrix_n for _ in range(matrix_m)]
block = [[1]*block_n for _ in range(block_m)]

def solution(matrix, block):
    from collections import deque
    
    m = len(matrix)
    n = len(matrix[0])
    
    bm = len(block)
    bn = len(block[0])
    
    d = deque()
    for r in range(bm):
            for c in range(bn):
                d.append(block[r][c])
                
    
    for row in range(m):
        for col in range(n):
            if matrix[row][col] == 0:
                if d:
                    matrix[row][col] = d.popleft()
                else:
                    break
    
    return matrix
            

solution(matrix, block)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

How to modify the `def(solution)` to get the expected output?

Does the below logic looks correct to find the next available block?

```
    for i,row in enumerate(block):
        for j,val in enumerate(row):
            while i<m and j<n:
                if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                    if d:
                        matrix[i][j] = d.popleft()
                    else:
                        break
            i += 1
            j += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an NP-Hard problem ... it is known as rectangle packing you can find some various algorithms pretty easily, but it is a computationally hard problem.. that said here is a modified version that correectly fills the matrix with just this one square

```
def solution(matrix, block):
    # make a copy to not overwrite original
    m2 = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
    for i,row in enumerate(block):
        for j,val in enumerate(row):
            # fill some squares with the values from "block"
            m2[i][j] = val
    return m2 # return copy
```

Comment: Thanks. can we also use  `copy.copy` here?

Comment: you might be able to ... im not sure though, I think that `copy.copy` that will create a shallow copy of the inner lists, which would modify the original passed in matrix (which might be fine... if it is you dont need the copy at all) ... its also possible im wrong and it doesnt change the original at all ... but if its ok to just change the origginal just dont make a copy and set `matrix[i][j]` instead of `m2[i][j]`

Comment: how to add the while loop after `for j,val in enumerate(row):` so as to keep check for space downwards in the bigger matrix?

Comment: added logic in my question. does that looks correct to you?